# How to add tables inside facebook instant articles?

Tags: facebook-instant-articles

In facebook format references https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/reference nothing is mentioned about adding tables. When I try to add tables inside

tags that is getting truncated by facebook. Is there anyone resolved this issue?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 5):

Tables are not supported out of the box. You can wrap them in an `op-interactive` though. They won't inherit any styling so you might need to add some styling as well.

```
<figure class="op-interactive">
    <iframe>
        <table>
        [...]
        </table>
    </iframe>
</figure>
```

Comment: it's good put `overflow-x: auto` if you want to enable horizontal scroll on your table. Thanks for your answer!!!

Comment: I tried adding the overflow-x in the `<table>` but didn't work so well. But adding addition `<div style="overflow-x:auto;">` to wrap around the `<table>` does make the table scroll horizontally