# How do I add text to a table in a Facebook Post or Note?

Tags: html, facebook, html-table

I've tried (and failed) to find a method for presenting text data in a table for a Facebook Post, Note, or other FB medium that can be viewed inline (sans downloading first) by any Facebook users.

I've tried the following methods:

1. Searching StackOverflow for ["facebook tables"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=facebook+tables). I found this hopeful result from 2016: [How to add tables inside facebook instant articles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37696023/how-to-add-tables-inside-facebook-instant-articles), but Instant Articles were closed by FB in April 2023, and op-interactive was closed by FB according to their [developer docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/).
2. [Embedding table text data in a Post/Note from a non-FB https source](https://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/embedding-your-content-on-a-facebook-page/). This method was closed by FB in 2017.
3. iFrames might be an option, but there's nothing in their developer docs indicating the syntax for pulling remote data in to a FB post. Additionally, if FB ever decides to close iFrames, all of my tabled data would be lost. Not real enthused about that risk.
4. FB's [Embedded Post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts/) option would be perfect, but it's only for importing FB data into a non-FB site.